# remote sensing in power supply

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator

Can someone explain how the opamp compensates voltage drop for this circuit.
lets assume that i need a 5V drop across load but instead im getting only 3V .
how will the opamp make ouput across load back to 5V?
[image: remote sensing]

*Reference: [TradeOfIC.com](http://www.tradeofic.com/Circuit/15301-Three_terminal_regulation_with_remote_sensing.html).*

Comment: Other than directing the voltage to the voltage divider on the ADJ pin?

Comment: I'm sorry i did not get you

Comment: Do you understand how the regulator itself works?

Comment: as an addendum to that last question, think about how an op-amp works too, and how that might affect things. If the voltage was 3V, what does the op-amp want to do?

Comment: Since its voltage follower the output of opamp is same as the voltage at the non inverting terminal which is 3V.

Comment: Now wat will be the current flowing into 121 ohm resistor?

Comment: lets say the reference of regulator is 1.25 V

Comment: Please help me out im really stuck at this point

Comment: I question the validity of that circuit. In conventional use, the top of the 121 ohm resistor would be connected directly to Vout and you wouldn't have the 301A op-amp.  But if you wanted to use remote-sensing, then the output of the 301A op-amp would drive the top of the 121 ohm resistor, and there would not be a hard connection to Vout.  I can't see how the output of the 301A op-amp can compete when hard-connected to the regulator Vout??

Comment: In remote sensing,If there was no hard connection how would the voltage regulator reference voltage get applied across the 121 ohm resistor?

Comment: and also please tell me why Rp is max 300mV? what does it mean?

Comment: Im guessing Rp is parasetic resistance, if so why is it max 300mV?

Comment: "how would the voltage regulator reference voltage get applied across the 121 ohm resistor?"  It gets the reference voltage through the 1K resistor into the non-inverting input pin (3) of the op-amp.

Comment: but if there is a line drop then 1.25V from reference would not get applied right?

Comment: so my output is reduced not increased?

Comment: Please add link (in your question) to the source of the schematic so we can review it in context.

Comment: http://www.tradeofic.com/Circuit/15301-Three_terminal_regulation_with_remote_sensing.html

Comment: That circuit is slightly different to the one you posted. See the 22 Ω resistor.

Comment: yes but i just want to know working of this circuit

Comment: But where did you get this circuit and why did you post a link to a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Actual circuit from [tradeofic.com](http://www.tradeofic.com/Circuit/15301-Three_terminal_regulation_with_remote_sensing.html). Note addition of 22 \$\Omega\$ resistor at (3).*

There are odd things about the circuit apart from the differences in the schematic you posted and the one in the link. The one in the link I can understand to some extent and will use that in this answer.

- The 317 style regulators settle down with 1.25 V between Vout and ADJ. With the component values in Figure 1 that means there is a 1.25 V drop across the 121 Ω resistor so current = \$ \frac {1.25}{121} = 10~mA\$.
- With no load connected \$V_2 = 10m(365+25) = 3.9~V\$. This will result in an output voltage of 3.9 + 1.25 = 5.15 V at (1).
- Again, with no load, \$ V_4 = V_1 = V_3 \$ as the op-amp is configured as a voltage follower.

Now let's apply a load and let's say it causes a 100 mV drop across \$ R_{DROP} \$.

- \$ V_4 \$ drops by 100 mV. \$ V_3 \$ does the same. This causes a 100 mV drop across the 22 Ω resistor and \$ \frac {0.1}{22} = 4.5~mA \$ will flow into A1 which will have to *sink* the current.
- At this point we should note that A1's negative terminal is connected to GND via the 25 Ω resistor. This sink currrent (and any quiescent current of A1) will return to GND through the 25 Ω resistor raising \$V_5\$ by \$ 4.5m \cdot 25 = 112~mV\$.
- Raising \$V_5\$ will therefore raise \$V_2\$ and ultimately \$V_1\$ by the same amount thus compensating for the voltage drop across \$R_{DROP}\$.

Points yet to be figured out:

- The LM301 has a quiescent current of 1.8 mA at \$V_S\$ = ±15V. You'd need to work out what it is on a single rail supply at \$ V_{IN} \$.
- The circuit appears to stabilise at a voltage *higher* than 5 V. Why?
  The 301 quiescent current will make this even worse.
- Normally a voltage compensating circuit would compensate for voltage drop in the feed *and* return lines. This circuit doesn't show the return line clearly. I would expect that the 25 Ω resistor should terminate at the load with a separate return wire. The compensation circuit components should then be chosen to adjust for *twice* the drop detected across \$ R_{DROP} \$ assuming that feed and return conductors are the same gauge.

**\$ V_{DROP} \$ limit of 300 mV**

[image]

*Figure 2. [LM301](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm101a-n.pdf) maximum current.*

Figure 11 of the datasheet shows the current limit at two temperatures. We're unlikely to be operating at such a high voltage and may be further limited. Let's pick 12 mA as maximum sink current to give some safety margin.

Remember that the sink current goes through the 25 Ω resistor giving a voltage rise to compensate for the voltage drop across \$ R_{DROP} \$. Therefore the maximum voltage rise the opamp can generate is \$12m \cdot 25 = 300~mV \$. This is the (design) maximum compensation of this circuit. It may work up to 400 or 500 mV but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: I have few doubts.

Comment: the voltage at non inverting terminal after the 100mV drop is 5.05V right?

Comment: So is 5.05V present at V3?

Comment: Please roll all your comments into one before hitting Enter. No, the circuit will maintain the load voltage at 5.15 V according to my calculations. V3 will be the same as at the load. V1 will rise to maintain 5.15 V at the load.

Comment: Why is Rdrop max 300mV? What does it mean?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Can you suggest me a power supply of 12V design which can compensate voltage upto 5V.

Comment: No. A web search for PSU with remote sense should throw up plenty of results. Please accept the answer if has told given you the information you require.